# Spring AMQP - what if I return null in a Rabbit listener method with @SendTo annotation?

Tags: spring-amqp

Spring AMQP doc says:

> Assuming our processOrder method should now return an OrderStatus, it
>   is possible to write it as follow to automatically send a reply:

```
@RabbitListener(destination = "myQueue")
@SendTo("status")
public OrderStatus processOrder(Order order) {
    // order processing
    return status;
}
```

What if I return a null at the end of the processOrder method? Will it send a null object to MQ or simply do nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you return `null`, no reply will be sent. Under TRACE level logging, you will see a log message `No result object given - no result to handle`.